# RB-77C Destroyer on March 10th, 1964 over Magdeburg

Tags: military, aviation-history

It is claimed that a spy plane with the registration RB-77C Destroyer was shot down near Magdeburg on 10 March 1964. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Re "Does anyone know anything about this?"-- without a doubt, "someone" does!  ; )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the correct date, and an *almost* correct aircraft designation; it was an RB-66C not a RB-77C:

> On 10 March 1964, a 19th TRS RB-66C flying on a photo-reconnaissance mission from the Toul-Rosières Air Base in France, was shot down over East Germany by a Soviet Mikoyan-Gurevich MiG-21 after it had crossed over the border due to a compass malfunction. The crew ejected from the aircraft and, following a brief period of detention, were repatriated to the United States.
> <sub>source: [Wikipedia - Douglas B66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_B-66_Destroyer)</sub>

This was covered by the printed news media of the day:

> WIESBADEN, Germany, March 21 — The Soviet Union released today an injured United States Air Force officer, one of three crewmen of an RB‐66 reconnaissance bomber shot down over East Germany 11 days ago.
>
> The officer, First Lieut. Harold W. Welch, navigator of the plane, was turned over to United States authorities in Magdeburg, East Germany, and brought to the Wiesbaden Air Force Hospital. He suffered a broken arm and leg when he landed in a tree after having parachuted from the burning jet.
> <sub>source: [New York Times - March 22, 1964, Page 1](https://www.nytimes.com/1964/03/22/archives/soviet-releases-injured-crewman-of-downed-rb66-detains-2-other.html)</sub>